# CSS to stack some elements to the bottom

Tags: css, google-chrome, chromium

I have a page with this HTML

```
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
<div>div 4</div>
... variable amount of divs
```

I want to create this layout, where the page is 100% tall and wide. The first two divs should be at the top, all following divs stacked at the bottom.

The divs are generated automatically - I can not treat the first two differently (only in the stylesheet).

How can I achieve this? I need only to support the latest version of Chrome and Chromium.

```
--------------------------
| ----------  ---------- |
| | div 1  |  |  div 2 | | <-- aligned to top of page
| |        |  |        | |
| ----------  ---------- |
|                        |
|                        | <-- variable space
|                        |
| ----------------       |
| |    div 3     |       |
| ----------------       | <-- aligned to bottom of page
| ----------------       |
| |    div 4     |       |
| ----------------       |
--------------------------
```

Comment: Any attempt of yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible to do the way I would have liked. I will treat the top and bottom divs differently (which I wanted to avoid) and wrap both of those groups in their own container like this:

*HTML*

```
<div id="top">
    <div><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div><h1>2</h1></div>
</div>

<div id="bottom">
    <div><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div><h1>5</h1></div>
    <div><h1>6</h1></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#top div {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `:nth-child` to target the first two divs and stack them in a row and leave the rest stacked at bottom..

Comment: I'm aware of the nth-child selector. Can you make an example of "leave the rest stacked at bottom"?

Comment: check the example [in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G59V3/1/), it doesn't matter if you add more and more divs, it will affect only the first two, and the rest will be stacked after them.

Comment: The divs are not at the bottom. I have improved my question to explain more clearly what I want to achieve.

Comment: you use a container for that divs?

Answer (score 0):

iterate through the divs on the page. Jquery can do this pretty easily.

```
$('div').each(function(i, elem) {
     //do something with the current 'elem'.
     //How do I know if its the first and 2nd div?
   if(i==1||i==2)
   {
   //This must be the first 2 divs  

}
   });
```

EDIT:I will add that this is a bad way to do this, but is easy to follow IMO. Say you have 1000 divs, you iterate through all of them just to process a few, etc.

EDIT AGAIN: So when I say //do something, I would do $(item).addClass('customCSS'). This will allow you to target these divs, regardless of how they are generated. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm looking for a CSS solution. The divs are generated by an angularjs ng-repeat. This won't play nicely with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
div:first-child{
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
}

div:nth-child(2){
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
}

div:nth-child(3){
   width: 100%;
   clear:both;
}

div:last-child{
   width: 100%;
   clear:both;
}
```

And follow this pattern with all the divs you have

Comment: I need them to stack to the bottom, else it would be easy.